# BeautifulSoup output is not transferred to CSV file

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export the output from a webscraper to a CSV file. The code works and I get the right output when I run it in the terminal, but it does not transfer to the CSV file.

**Question**

*When I remove the first for loop it works fine, but I can't figure out exactly what the error it in this part?*

**Code**

```
import csv ; import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open('ImplementTest8.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["job_link", "job_desc"])

res = requests.get("http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")

for li in soup.find('ul', class_='list-articles list').find_all('li'):
    level = li.find_all('dd', {'class': 'author'})[1].get_text()
    if "Graduate" in level:
        links = li.find_all("href")
        for link in links:
            if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
                item_link = link.get("href").strip()
                item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").encode('utf-8').strip()
                writer.writerow([item_link, item_text])
                print(item_link, item_text)
```

**Edited Code**

```
import csv ; import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open('ImplementTest8.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["job_link", "job_desc"])

res = requests.get("http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")

for li in soup.find('ul', class_='list-articles list').find_all('li'):
    level = li.find_all('dd', {'class': 'author'})[1].get_text()
    if "Graduate" in level:
        links = li.find_all(href=True)
        for link in links:
            if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
                item_link = link.get("href").strip()
                item_text = link.text.replace("View Position","").encode('utf-8').strip()
                writer.writerow([item_link, item_text])
                print(item_link, item_text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Href is a tag attribute not a tag name. if you want to ensure that all your links have a href attribute you can use it as a [keyward argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments), else use the tag name.

```
links = li.find_all(href=True)
```

Comment: Thanks T.M - I just tried to change the code from (href) to (href=True), but it gives me the following error:   File "<stdin>", line 4 SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: Don't use quotes in `href`, it's an argument name not an argument value. The value is `True`

Comment: Got it - the CSV sheet is still empty. I have added in the edited code above.

Comment: Sorry - the csv file took a little bit of time to create. Thanks - this solved my issue.